# SSIS 2008 painfully slow to import CSV

Tags: ado.net, ssis, performance

I am using SSIS to import a 25,000 row CSV to an empty table.  The table has a primary key that is populated as the data is inserted.  I am using an ADO.Net destination.

What reasons are there why this operation would take around 5 minutes?  At the default value of DefaultBufferMaxRows (10,000), the import fails completely with a timeout after around 5,000 rows.  I dropped the value to 1,000 and now it gets there eventually with no timeout, but takes a full five minutes.

The Flat File data source has explicit column widths set, could that be the issue?

Comment: is it a straight import or are you doing any transformations?

Comment: only setting explicit column widths on the flat file datasource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'answer' was that the ADO.Net providers in SSIS are basically useless and an embarrassment to the '.Net' moniker.  They flake at more than a few thousand rows and are so hobbled as to be effectively useless.  Basically, just stick to the old OLEDB providers and everything will be fine.

Comment: +1 - I was about to suggest using OLEDB providers for the destination.  One caveat though - if you're going from an ADO.NET source you may have to do unicode to ANSI conversions on anything where the destination is a varchar column.

Comment: Good point, but I basically converted everything to OLEDB and haven't looked back.

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts:

- Any triggers on the table?
- What happens when the PK is dropped? Or what happens when you load a key-less staging table, before loading the real table?
- Is the log or data file growing? (aka has it been previously shrunk by some *clever* person)

Comment: No triggers.  This is a staging table, I'll try it without the key.  I'll check the log, thanks.

Comment: Actually, there are several constraints on the table, and one default constraint.  Would these make a difference?

Comment: Okay, the constraints and the key also don't make a difference.

Comment: I have now tried it on the server and it's just as slow, so it's not the network.

Comment: @Craig: check for other issues such as IO or log errors. Try batch size too

Comment: @gbn even locally on my machine it is slow.  I changed to using an OLE Destination, and it's still slow.  Then I tried the SQL Server Destination.  That is fast, but doesn't let me run it from my machine and target a remote server.

Comment: @Craig: well, I'm out of ideas sorry...

Answer (score 1):

Some other thoughts on diagnosing the fault:

- try creating a completely new table, with no constraints/PK etc and seeing if this effects the load
- try the same on a different machine
- try putting some data viewers on the DFT, and seeing how far/fast the
  data is flowing around your DFT?
- when you are using sql destination are you using fast load?

Comment: Dropping all constraints and indexes made no difference. Neither did running it locally.  Can you explain about DFT and data viewers?  Not sure what you mean?

I am using ADO.Net Destination, which does not appear to have fast load?

Comment: Actually ... a more basic question, what version of SQL are you using, and how are "importing" the table, is it by a) writing a Data Flow Task (DFT), or b) using the import/export wizard?

Comment: SQL 2008 SP1 and I'm using Data Flow Tasks, yes.

Comment: sry @Craig, I didnt reply to your previous qn on data viewers. A data viewer allow you to see tables/graphs of data as it flows through a data flow task. But if you have only an "Excel source" and a "SQL destination" in tyour DFT, then it will be obvious by running in VisualStudio/BIDS how quickly the records are being processed and if the bottleneck is in the reading or the writing. Another diagnosis idea is in the DFT to have the "excel source" and a "trash destination" (try http://bit.ly/gJHtDb). This will show if it is the read or the write that is the problem